# Compiler/linker error

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

i'm trying to make my program work(different from earlier one) and im still getting some compiler/linker error i have no idea how to fix, can anyone guide me on some solutions to fixing the linker/compiler or whatever it is?

here is the build log im getting:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in lab1hwfinal (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -I..\Documents -c   
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\lab1hwfinal\main.o
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp:19:5: error: 'complexType' was not
declared in this scope
 complexType sum;
 ^
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp:19:17: error: expected ';' before 
'sum'
 complexType sum;
             ^
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp:26:15: error: 'exit' was not declared 
in this scope
     exit(1);
           ^
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp:45:38: error: 'atof' was not declared
in this scope
     realpart= atof(strone.c_str());
                                  ^
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp:48:21: error: expected ';' before 
'outpobj'
     complexType outpobj(realpart, imaginarypart);
                 ^
C:\Users\Dekkiller\Documents\lab1hwfinal\main.cpp:51:54: error: 'outpobj' was not 
declared in this scope
     outputfile << "Object " << counter << "-" << outpobj << endl;
                                                  ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Here is my main file:

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream outputfile;
ifstream inputfile;
string str;
double realpart;
double imaginarypart;
int symbol;
char ch;
string strone;
string strtwo;
complexType sum;
int counter = 0;

inputfile.open("complex.txt");
if(inputfile.fail())
{
    cout << "File opening failed." << endl;
    exit(1);
}

outputfile.open("complexObj.txt");

inputfile >> str;
while(inputfile)
{
    symbol=str.find("+");
    ch = '+';
    if(symbol < 0)
    {
        symbol = str.find("-");
        ch = '-';
    }
    stringstream streamin(str);
    getline(streamin, strone, ch);
    getline(streamin, strtwo, 'i');

    realpart= atof(strone.c_str());
    imaginarypart= atof(strtwo.c_str());

    complexType outpobj(realpart, imaginarypart);
    counter++;

    outputfile << "Object " << counter << "-" << outpobj << endl;

    inputfile.close();
    outputfile.close();

    return 0;
}

}
```

my header class file:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
#include <iostream>


class complexType
{
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const complexType& obj);
public:
  complexType();
  complexType(double r, double i);
  complexType operator+(const complexType& objtwo);
private:
    double real;
    double imagine;
};

#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

here is my class cpp file:

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


complexType::complexType()
{
real=0;
imagine=0;
}

complexType::complexType(double r, double i)
{
real=r;
imagine=i;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const complexType& obj)
{
os << obj.real << "," << obj.imagine;
return os;
}

complexType complexType::operator+(const complexType& objtwo)
{
complexType sum;
sum.real = real + objtwo.real;
sum.imagine = imagine + objtwo.imagine;
return sum;
}
```

I'm sorry for asking such similar questions but i can't figure out what is wrong with my linker or compiler.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are the files in the same catalogue? Are they named "Complex.h" and "Complex.cpp"?

Comment: Hi i'm using the GNU GCC Compileron the selected compiler, i believe the compiler that came with my install of codeblocks was MinGW.

Comment: Make sure your files `Complex.h` and `Complex.cpp` are either in the same directory as your main file or in the `Documents` folder that you refer to with the `-I` argument.  (Although, if they are in `Documents` then you will have to do something explicitly link in `Complex.o` on the command line as well.  Easiest would just to be to put all of the files into the same folder.)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like complex.h is a reserved name. Try to rename you header and it should work.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/basedefs/complex.h.html